# Prevent Jenkins job from launching additional jobs with git commit

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm attempting to create a Jenkins pipeline which does the following steps at a high level:

1. Send build notifications
2. Run lint tests
3. Run CI tests
4. Update version information in a couple of files
5. Use git to commit the updates to the files, create tags, and push changes to origin
6. Upload files in project to another system
7. Send notifications

I want this pipeline to execute when a commit happens to specific branches. I have this working now, but the issue is when the job commits the new changes during the build (in step 5 above), it launches a new build and essentially enters an infinite loop.

I know this is working by design right now, but is there anyway way to prevent a new build job from executing? Can I do something within the Jenkins pipeline to prevent the new commit from launching a new Jenkins job, or would this require a whole rework of the workflow?

Comment: Jeff, did you figure out how to deal with that issue?
I'm thinking about using "when GIT_COMMITTER_NAME!=Jenkins", but I'll need to do this check on *each* stage :-(
Is there better solution?

Comment: Yes, for this specific pipeline, we were modifying the version information in a file, pushing those changes, creating a tag and release, then pushing those changes to GitHub. I'm getting all of the tags in the git repo and finding the latest commit for the most recent tag. It then compares that commit sha to the latest commit sha in the git repo.  If they match, then I know this repository was already released and up to date.

Here's sample code from the pipeline -- Hope this helps: https://gist.github.com/jeffreycoe/9d10aaf0d773338fd54773b51729e763

Comment: Just to clarify - I wasn't able to stop the push event from launching another Jenkins build job, but this latest commit verification stage would allow me to exit the new build job early with a successful status. The only minor issue I found so far is if the previous job fails after it committed the new version files and created a new tag and release in GitHub, the next build which exits successfully after the commit verification stage will report a successful build in GitHub as it is the last build for that commit. This was not an issue with our pipeline, though.

Comment: Jeff, many thanks for your answer!
After some investigation and found and used https://plugins.jenkins.io/ignore-committer-strategy/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [generic-webhook-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin),

For instance, GitHub webhooks in Jenkins are used to trigger the build whenever a developer commits something to the branch, in each webhook we have following info

```
git repository name
branch which was changed
commit id
commit message
commit author
etc ...
```

To avoid loop

- save Jenkins commit ID to file and add the file to git ignore
- read remote commit ID from push using generic webhook trigger
- compare local file commit ID with Remote commit ID
- If same it's mean commit from Jenkins, if not it's mean commit is not from Jenkins

Here is the snippet that may help or change accordingly, it will not create look

```
#!/bin/bash
webhook_commit_id=$commit
commit_by_jenkins=commit_by_jenkins.txt
if [ ! -f $commit_by_jenkins ]
then
    echo "creating local file name commit_by_jenkins.txt, please add this file to git ignore"
    touch commit_by_jenkins.txt
fi
jenkins_commit=`cat commit_by_jenkins.txt`
if [ "${webhook_commit_id}" == "${jenkins_commit}" ]; then 
    echo "commit by jekins server, ignoring commit"
else
      echo "commiting code from jenkins servver"
      git add -A && git commit -m "commit by jenkins server" && git rev-parse HEAD > commit_by_jenkins.txt
fi
```

Comment: Thanks - Is there a way to do this similarly when using the Branch API plugin? We configured our Jenkins instance with a GitHub Organization multibranch pipeline plugin which I believe uses the Branch API plugin when launching new builds with each new commit. I was going through the plugin code and I wasn't sure if there was a way to pull the webhook data or any commit information when using these plugins.

Comment: I'm non sure but my experience was with branch API was not, generics web hook is what you need at the need

Comment: https://docs.branch.io/apps/deep-linking-api/ if you are using this plugin then you ca do the same but for that you need to use `tag`